# Can we pass different type of input format files in MultipleInput class in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

Can we pass different type of input format files i.e. `TextInputFormat` and `SequenceInputFormat` in `MultipleInput` in Hadoop?

just like below:

MultipleInputs.addInputPath(jobConf, 
                     new Path(dictionarySource), 
                     **SomeInputFormat**.class, 
                     TranslateMapper.class);

MultipleInputs.addInputPath(jobConf, 
                     new Path(dictionarySource), 
                     **SomeOtherInputFormat**.class, 
                     TranslateMapper.class);

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes, [that parameter](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleInputs.html) is any extension of `InputFormat`

```
Class<? extends InputFormat> inputFormatClass
```

Longer answer for the follow up of "how do you handle that in the Reducer?" - The reducer inputs must be the same as the mapper outputs, which can be anything you want

Comment: Hi, my concern is if I want to read and process text and json format together in a single MapReduce program, what would be the solution?

Comment: JSON is also a text format, so it'll still work. Whatever text that isn't JSON will just throw an exception that you need to catch